# Saving vector<int> to file

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, save

Really strange that I didn't find an answer to this question on stackoverflow.

I want to save a `std::vector<int>` to a file. 
At various places I found the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512};
std::ofstream outfile("test.data", std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile));
outfile.close();
```

But the problem here is, that the `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>` converts each of the values of `v` to a `char` before writing it to a file. Therefore  the values `256` and `512` are changed to `0`. The resulting file looks like this under hexedit:

```
00000000   00 01 02 04  08 10 20 40  80 00 00
```

My idea was to change `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>` to `std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>`, but that doesn't work. The compiler throws the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>::ostreambuf_iterator(std::ofstream&)’
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>(outfile));
```

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: `#include <ostream>` and `#include <iterator>`. Also probably `#include <fstream>`

Comment: @Arunmu Both are included.

Comment: Simply remove `| std::ofstream::binary`. You don't want a binary file anyway.

Comment: `std::ostreambuf_iterator` requires template argument to be a char type. You could try to use `wchar`, but it still would fail for the values greater than 65535. Why not simply write vector to the file stream using `<<` operator?

Comment: @Alf The values still getting converted to ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize to binary, just remember issues such as endianness and you will be fine. Basically, use std::ofstream and ifstream write() and read().

Two progs for serializing and unserializing are shown below, quick hacks, so there may be errors:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ios;

int main()
{
    vector<int> datavec{0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512};

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open ("datafile.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

    for (auto val : datavec) {
        outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&val), sizeof(int));
        if (outfile.bad()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write to outfile!");
        }
    }

    cout << "Wrote data to file. Done.\n";
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;
using std::ios_base;

int main()
{
    vector<int> datavec;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("datafile.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    while (infile) {
        int val;
        infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&val), sizeof(int));
        if (infile.bad()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read from infile!");
        }
        if (infile.eof()) break;
        datavec.push_back(val);
    }

    cout << "Read data file. Contents of datavec: \n";
    for (auto val : datavec) {
        cout << val << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\nDone\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted. Before pushing the read value to the vector, we have to make the branch `if (infile.eof()) break;`. Otherwise the last read value gets pushed twice.

Comment: @user38034 Good point, I modified the src code with the additional line you  suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `std::ostream_iterator`, not `std::ostreambuf_iterator`.

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512};
std::ofstream outfile("test.data", std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);

std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(outfile));
outfile.close();
```

Note that the resulting output is:

```
01248163264128256512
```

This just writes the values in the `int` vector to the output stream, as if using the `<<` operator, but without any separators, which may or may not be what you really want. But that's what it does.

Comment: yes this is the best way to do it. Even if you want to pass a delimiter like "\n", " ", ","  etc you can pass that as the second argument to std::ostream_iterator<int>() and it will save that in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, remove the `std::ofstream::binary` when creating the stream (you can also remove `std::ios::out` as that is the default for an `ofstream` anyway).

The main thing is to use `std::ostream_iterator<int>` instead of `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>`.

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512};
std::ofstream outfile("test.data");
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(outfile));
outfile.close();
```

You might also want to add a delimiter when creating the `ostream_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to write the integers to the file as characters then you can use [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&outfile](int x){outfile << x;});
```

This will write the integers as strings to the file on one line with no whitespace between them, i.e.:

> 01248163264128256512